# how spring cache define a prefix?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

My company is using spring version 4.2.Release. I want to add spring cache feature, with redis. What i'am confused about is how to custom a prefix for my biz key?
I known there is 2 way to define key

a. key

```
@Cacheable(value = CacheConstants.REDIS_CACHE, key = CacheConstants.CLASSES_PREFIX + "#classId")
```

But this type spring will get an error :

> EL1041E:(pos 2): After parsing a valid expression, there is still
>   more data in the expression: 'colon(:)'

I use like this but not `@Cacheable(value = CacheConstants.REDIS_CACHE, key = "'cn.cnt.concat'.concat(#classId)")` because this way is hard code in class.

b. keyGenerator

If use keyGenerator, we can customer a key. But can not pass the bizKey prefix to a keyGenerator. once so, we cannot invalid(del) a key in other @CacheEvict methods which update biz datas.

So, in this two way, there seems no way to custom a prefix to a key?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this like for dynamic key

```
@Cacheable(value = CacheConstants.REDIS_CACHE,key="'"+CacheConstants.CLASSES_PREFIX+"'#classId")
```

Comment: thx a lot  ,i solved the question use this style : 
@Cacheable(value = CacheConstants.REDIS_CACHE, key = "'" + CacheConstants.CLASSES_PREFIX + "'+#classId")

Comment: @D.TS what is the difference between your final style and mine.

Comment: see  "'+#classId" the last ,there must a "+" sign.